# Can I update to iTunes 9 with a Jailbroken iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, jailbreak

I have an iPhone with 3.0.1 firmware that has been Jailbroken, can I update iTunes to version 9 or will 'badness' happen?

Comment: Your best bet is to search the forums and see what others have to say.

Comment: I find I trust my fellow SuperUsers better than the @#$@#$ in the forums - if anyone writes a stupid answer here it gets edited/deleted or down voted into oblivion. (They have yet to find as good a filter for stupid questions!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it'll still be fine. What you won't be able to do is install OS 3.1 and keep your cracked apps.

Comment: I have updated iTunes to verion 9 and my iPhone is still intact. I am waiting on the proper tools to upgrade to 3.1 :)

Answer (score 2):

I've upgraded to iTunes 9, and haven't had any problems. When prompted to download and upgrade the iPhone to OS 3.1, don't do so. 
(I have an iPhone 3G on OS 3.0, Jailbroken & unlocked)

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to follow the [Dev-Team blog](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/): when the jailbreak for 3.1 (or any other version) is available, it's posted there...